# How to make the line spacing of different sections in one chapter?

Tags: sectioning, line-spacing

I have a chapter in my report that has many sections. For some reason, I would like to make the line spacing for some section equal `1` and `1.5` for some others.

So for example I have a chapter called `Welcome` and it has three sections `Start`, `Steps`, and `End`. I would like to make the line spacing of section `Start` equals `1` and the line spacing of section `Steps` equals `1.5` and the line spacing of section `End` equals `2`.

I did this but it is not working:

```
\chapter{Welcome}
    \section{Start}\linespread{1}
        blabla
    \section{Steps}\linespread{1.5}
        blabla
    \section{End}\linespread{2}
        blabla
```

It could be very easy to do it. I do not know. Is this even possible? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `setspace` package is here for that: it defines `\onehalfspacing`, `\doublespacing` and `\simplespacing` switches, and corresponding environments.

Comment: 1st of all: Why different linespacings? 2nd: **It could be very easy to do it and it could not be done**. What does this mean? Are you asking for a automatical change in a section lineup *Start - Steps - End*?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry if I didn't write it clearly. I meant that maybe LaTeX won't let me do different line spacing or maybe it is a simple command.
For the reason, It is an obligation from my university. I have to write the report with `1` line spacing in one section and with `1.5` line spacing in other sections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `setspace` package (cf. `l2tabu`, § 1.4). There are several reasons for that:

- `\linespread` modifies the value of `\baselinestretch` indiscriminately. Quite often, one does not want to modify the spacing in footnotes or in list or floating  environments.
- Unlike one may naively think, typographic rules make onehalf spacing, for instance not the equivalent of `\linespread{1.5}`, but of `\linespread{1.25}`, if you're using 10pt (this varies with the font size). Similarly, `double spacing` is `\linespread{1.667}` for 10 pt.

`setspace` takes care of all this. It defines environments `singlespace, doublespace`and  `one halfspace` and the corresponding commands `\singlespacing, \doublespacing` and  `\onehalfspacing`. The value used by singlespace (of course, 1 by default) may be changed with the `\SetSinglespace` command.

If you want a custom spacing,   you have the `spacing` environment and the `\setstretch` command, which both take one argument.

Comment: Besides, `\linespread{1.5}` does nothing by itself and it should be followed by `\selectfont`.

Comment: @egreg: I didn't know that. Thanks for the information!